# Typecast ArrayList to ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, casting, http-status-codes

I am facing an issue in typecasting an ArrayList to ResponseEntity. I make a native query call to the DB to fetch the resultset. Once I get the resultset, I typecast the arraylist to ResponseEntity so that I get the httpStatusCode to build my response. But typecasting throws me an error.
Below is the code snippet

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getAllStudentEnquiry() {
logger.info("Getting all student enquiry details");
ResponseEntity<List<SmsEnquiry>> studentList= (ResponseEntity<List<SmsEnquiry>>) smsEnquiryRespository.findAll();
return studentList;
}
```

**All I want from this response is the httpStatus to decide on the response that I build.
Pls help**

Answer (score 0):

1. Casting Object,

   The source and destination classes must be related by inheritance; one class must be a subclass of the other.
2. Construct a new response entity with query result.

   ```
   ResponseEntity<List<SmsEnquiry>> studentList = new ResponseEntity<>(smsEnquiryRespository.findAll(),HttpStatus.OK);
   ```